# OpenCV PCA giving nan values

Tags: c++, opencv, nan, opencv3.0, pca

Using C++ OpenCV 3.1.0 PCA.

Implemenation giving nan values, my PCA function is

```
Mat PCA_doer(Mat& tdata, int feature_sel = 180)
{
Mat average;
PCA pca(tdata, average, CV_PCA_DATA_AS_ROW, feature_sel);
Mat newdata = Mat::zeros(tdata.rows, feature_sel,tdata.type());
pca.project(tdata,newdata);

return newdata;
}
```

Data (original input) is of form (this is to give you an idea its in saved in row major form):

```
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
BBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB
CCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCCC
```

and so on (about 9000 samples x 248 features, reducing to 180 features),
input is a standard floating point matrix, if you can imagine values between -ve somthing and positive something then its that. The matrix is way too large to post here so the above should give you an idea

**output after doing PCA is nan**

output is of form:

```
 -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan,
 -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, 
-nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan, -nan]
```

(you get the idea)

what am I doing wrong?

Edit:

**Yes I'm undeleting this so that if someone ever faces the same problem, its as Micka said, my input was nan.
I was doing feature scaling by vector normalization which was converting some values to nan before feeding to the pca. Hence the result.**

Problem #2 though, PCA worsens the result, why could this happen?

Comment: are there (some few) nan in your input data?

Comment: all of it is nan

Comment: your INPUT is nan?

Comment: Obviously this depends on what is your input - the only thing you didn't show. Find a minimal data set that allows to reproduce the problem and include it in your post.

Comment: input is a standard floating point matrix. I could link you to a raw pastebin of the whole matrix if you want?

Comment: input was nan, Micka, Barto seems you were right